# Nifi manipulate all Json Key Values from Invokehttp

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a json that comes from InvokeHTTP. I did a Split Json and JoltTransform to get the Key, Values, but I need to change all the Keys from Camelcase to snakecase.

My Keys will be different with every InvokeHttp call. I've tried AttributestoJson and EvaluateJsonPath and some replace text, but haven't figured out a way to dynamically change just the keys and then merge back to the values without writing a custom processor.

Original Data from InvokeHTTP:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Table": [
      {
        "Age": 51,
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Doe"
      },
      {
        "Age": 26,
        "FirstName": "Ryan",
        "LastName": "Doe"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Input after Split Json (Gives me each json in a separate flowfile) and Jolt:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "Age",
    "Value": 51
  },
  {
    "Key": "FirstName",
    "Value": "Bob"
  },
  {
    "Key": "LastName",
    "Value": "Doe"
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Table": [
      {
        "age": 51,
        "first_name": "Bob",
        "last_name": "Doe"
      },
      {
        "age": 26,
        "first_name": "Ryan",
        "last_name": "Doe"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what about execute script ?

Comment: That is the route I figured out a few hours ago. Still having some problems getting that to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the fields, you can use JoltTransformJSON on the original input JSON so you don't have to use SplitJson, here's a spec that will do the (explicit) field name conversion:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "Table": {
          "*": {
            "Age": "data.Table[#2].age",
            "FirstName": "data.Table[#2].first_name",
            "LastName": "data.Table[#2].last_name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You could also use UpdateRecord, you'd just need separate schemas for the JsonTreeReader and JsonRecordSetWriter.

Comment: The fields will change on every invokehttp call, so that could make the Jolt approach less dynamic. I'll take a look at JsonTreeReader and SetWriter

Comment: If the fields will change, take a look at InferAvroSchema as well. However lowercasing them will be more of a challenge, you may want to continue with your ExecuteScript, feel free to post an SO question with whatever trouble you're having there, and I will jump in and help out (please tag me if you can so I get notified :))

Comment: How can I executescript to a json instead of a string? @mattyb

Comment: In Groovy you can use JsonOutput, it'll be easier to explain in a separate SO question :)

Comment: Sorry missed when you said SO earlier, I figured out the json part, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52156115/70465) which uses `ReplaceText` to replace `.` in JSON keys with `_`. The same logic could be applied here (template available in link). As I pointed out in that answer, a cleaner solution would be to use `ExecuteScript`, especially as the transformation from camelcase to snakecase is done easily in most scripting languages.

Comment: I see how something like that could work. But I'm having trouble doing it to just the keys and not the value. I tried executescript, but didn't get that to work yet.

Comment: I did it by including the `:` in a look-ahead group in the regex. In a script, you’d have programmatic access to keys vs. values.